# python-social-auth with Django: ImportError: No module named 'social_django'

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-social-auth

**ALL packages installed!!**
Hi, I'm using python 3.5 Django==1.10 I installed Python-social-auth executed the command Python manage.py transfer error received!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 22, in 
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/home/berluskuni/web_project/exprender/.exprender/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/django
/core/management/init.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/home/berluskuni/web_project/exprender/.exprender/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/init.py", line 341, in execute
django.setup()
File "/home/berluskuni/web_project/exprender/.exprender/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/django/init.py", line 27, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/home/berluskuni/web_project/exprender/.exprender/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
app_config.import_models(all_models)
File "/home/berluskuni/web_project/exprender/.exprender/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 199, in import_models
self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/importlib/init.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "", line 986, in _gcd_import
File "", line 969, in _find_and_load
File "", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "", line 673, in _load_unlocked
File "", line 665, in exec_module
File "", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/home/berluskuni/web_project/exprender/.exprender/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/social/apps/django_app/default/models.py", line 1, in 
from social_django.models import AbstractUserSocialAuth, UserSocialAuth, Nonce, Association, Code, DjangoStorage
ImportError: No module named 'social_django'
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

To use Django with python social auth, you need to install the Django app as well.

You can specify that you want to install the extra requirements for Django when you install `python-social-auth`:

```
pip install python-social-auth[django]
```

Or, in this case, you can install the missing package individually:

```
pip install social-auth-app-django
```

Comment: Successfully installed social-auth-app-django-0.1.0, 
python manage.py migrate, ImportError: No module named 'social_auth'

Answer (score 6):

Probably you should use pip 3:

```
pip3 install social-auth-app-django
```

Answer (score 4):

USE     `pip install python-social-auth[django]` instead of    `pip install python-social-auth` while installing

---

i have
first done install
`pip install python-social-auth`

### Run

**error**: No module named 'social_django'

**Then i install**

```
pip install python-social-auth[django]
```

**RUN**

Operations to perform:
Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, music, sessions, social_django
Running migrations:
Applying social_django.0001_initial... OK
Applying social_django.0002_add_related_name... OK
Applying social_django.0003_alter_email_max_length... OK
Applying social_django.0004_auto_20160423_0400... OK
Applying social_django.0005_auto_20160727_2333... OK
Applying social_django.0006_partial... OK

---

Running migrations:

**For extra support**

Migrating from python-social-auth to split social

[enter link description here](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/blob/master/MIGRATING_TO_SOCIAL.md)

Answer (score 2):

Just run:

```bash
pip install social-auth-app-django
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using pipenv like me don't forget to enter the shell and then install (I forgot to do so and it caused similar errors):

```
pipenv shell
pipenv install python-social-auth-app-django
```

then add social_django to install apps

I understand this wasn't the original question but hope it helps.