# An error while migrating -"no module named 'social_django'."

Tags: django

I have installed `python-social-auth==0.3.6`. Then I migrated and got an error:

```
from social_django.models import AbstractUserSocialAuth, UserSocialAuth, Nonce, Association, Code, DjangoStorage
ImportError: No module named 'social_django'
```

Comment: also i have installed: pip install python-social-auth[django] and pip install social-auth-app-django. but the same error occurs. Django version ==1.10.5

Comment: If you `pip freeze` what do you get?

Comment: (bookmarks) C:\Python34>pip freeze
defusedxml==0.5.0
Django==1.10.6
django-allauth==0.31.0
oauthlib==2.0.2
Pillow==2.9.0
PyJWT==1.4.2
python-social-auth==0.3.6
python3-openid==3.1.0
requests==2.13.0
requests-oauthlib==0.8.0
six==1.10.0
social-auth-app-django==1.1.0
social-auth-core==1.2.0

Comment: That's strange. I have the exact same virtualenv and works brilliantly, without errors. Have you actually used this package inside your project, somewhere?

Comment: Actually as i told  I am beginner. so i am doing this project with the help of the book. I had a lot of  problem and I solved them, but this one is really difficult for me. about the package-could specify which package pls

Comment: Did not help. the same error.

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATE]: What worked for me was this:

1. In a clean virtualenv I `pip install python-social-auth[django]`
2. I included `'django_social',` in my `INSTALLED_APPS`
3. I run migrations, `./manage.py migrate`

You need to install `python-social-auth[django]`:

```
pip install python-social-auth[django]
```

And then add `'social.apps.django_app.default'` to your [`INSTALLED_APPS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#std:setting-INSTALLED_APPS).

Then don't forget to run the migrations: `./manage.py migrate`

Comment: ISTALLED_APPS:INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'account',
    'images',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'social.apps.django_app.default',  but the same error

Comment: AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS:AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social.backends.facebook.Facebook2OAuth2',
    'social.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
    'social.backends.twitter.TwitterOAuth',

    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'account.authentication.EmailAuthBackend',

Comment: Did you `pip install social-auth-app-django` ?

Comment: yes i have installed pip install social-auth-app-django

Comment: You have `Django` installed, don't you? `pip install Django`

Comment: I have Django installed==1.10.5 and also I installed pip install soical-auth-app-django and added 'social.apps.django_app.default' to INSTALLED_APPS, then made migration but the same error

Comment: Did not got u.sorry I am  begginer in django. could you specify your recommendation

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41635052/python-social-auth-with-django-importerror-no-module-named-social-django)?

Comment: The same erro. Ye i have checked

Answer (score 0):

I resolve with

```
pip install django-rest-framework-social-oauth2==1.0.4 social-auth-core==0.2.1 python-social-auth==0.2.21 django-oauth-toolkit==0.10.0
```