# ImportError: No module named 'social_django'

Tags: python, django

Every time I am running the application from the [Github Repository](https://github.com/Prithvi45/Django-Social-Authentication), I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/lenovo-pc/Desktop/Django-Social-Authentication-master/socialauth/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 338, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 94, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'social_django'
```

I want to know what is `social_django` all about? I have installed many libraries, but non of then have satisfied this error:

```
python-social-auth[django]
social-auth-app-django
```

But nothing happens. Please let me know what I should do.

Comment: have you installed this `pip install python-social-auth[django]`

Comment: I guess I have mentioned it in the question already....

Comment: Update your INSTALLED_APPS to include social_django @jaffer

Reference:[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41635052/python-social-auth-with-django-importerror-no-module-named-social-django)

Comment: This is kinda late by I faced the same problem and solved it by adding the Pipfile and Pipfil.lock manually before committing to Heroku.

Comment: @Theodore could you add more details to your answer ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python executable you use to run the application doesn't have `social_django` installed. You can verify this by running these commands:

```
python manage.py shell
import social_django
```

This will give you an error, for the same reason.

You can install it with:

```
pip install social-auth-app-django
```

Comment: My reply is kinda late but I am facing this same issue, i tried the import and it worked fine without any errors  but i still get module not found error

Answer (score 1):

The github project you are referring to, has dependency on package 'social_django'. You can check it [here](https://github.com/Prithvi45/Django-Social-Authentication/blob/master/socialauth/socialauth/settings.py#L42).

So you would need to install 'social_django' that can be installed by

```
pip install social-auth-app-django
```

I know, you have mentioned this in the question itself but I am pretty sure that the package is not installed.